# How to make apps stay in the background without being killed?

Tags: android, background

Hi so I got a new phone but the apps I need to stay in the background keep on being killed. I have turned off battery optimization and used the don'tkillmyapp said it was 100% not much help. I looked around and someone mentioned that you can make apps stay in the background using adb. Can you please link a website on how to do that since I'm a beginner or you can just tell me how. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Worker. You can use workers for a specific task or to run others periodically. Here I leave the link for more information.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker&ved=2ahUKEwiQjZyz6JbuAhUm2FkKHQheAnIQFjABegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw3RUYn3s9t_S_Mks1x4p8H0

Comment: Thank you for the link.